# POST data into MySQL with NodeJS and Postman

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, postman

I'm a beginner in general and trying to use MySQL with nodeJS to be able to integrate projects in WordPress.

```
app.post('/users/add', (req, res) => {
  id = req.body.id, firstname = req.body.firstname, surname = 
  req.body.surname  
  let sql = "INSERT INTO `users_tbl` VALUES (id, firstname, surname)";          

  db.query(sql, [id, firstname, surname], 
  (err, rows, fields) => {

    if(!err) 
      res.send("User successfully added");
    else 
      console.log(err);
  });
})
```

With the given code I can add through Postman an entry, but an empty one.
I already tried to assign my values to the keys after VALUES, but maybe my syntax was wrong

Comment: `id = req.body.id, firstname = req.body.firstname, surname = 
  req.body.surname` - implicit globals? Yikes! Start using ESLint ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using [this module](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql).

---

> ```
> db.query(sql, [id, firstname, surname]
> ```

Here you are passing variables into your query for them to replace placeholder values.

---

> ```
> let sql = "INSERT INTO `users_tbl` VALUES (id, firstname, surname)";
> ```

But here you have just put column names instead of placeholder markers.

Change that to:

```
let sql = "INSERT INTO `users_tbl` VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

---

Aside: You should probably have the `id` field be an auto-increment field and not a user-submitted value.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.post('/users/add', (req, res) => {
   id = req.body.id, 
   firstname = req.body.firstname, 
   surname = req.body.surname  
   let sql = "INSERT INTO `users_tbl` (id, firstname, surname) VALUES 
              (?,?,?)";          

   db.query(sql, [id, firstname, surname], (err, rows, fields) => {
       if(!err) 
         res.send("User successfully added");
       else 
         console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Try this code just replace your values with ? and run postman again.

Answer (score -2):

Add a breakpoint or use console.log to check if you are actually getting the body fields in req.body.
Try setting 'Content-Type' as application/json in headers while sending the request through postman and send raw json in body.